# xilinx create schematic of top modul with lower level moduls

Tags: fpga, vhdl, schematics, xilinx

I have a top modul VHDL source file, which has a few instances of lower-level modules (VHDL) and signals which connects these lower-level modules. How can I generate a schematic for this? I mean, I would like to see the top module, inside it, the lower-level modules and the signals. (xilinx ise design suite 14.7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xilinx ISE 14.7: Design tab -> Synthesize - XST (expand node) -> View RTL Schematic.

Alternative: menu Tools -> Schematic Viewer -> RTL...

*RTL Schematic* (Register Transfer Logic) is the generic, hierarchical schematic in terms of combinational logic and flip-flops.  The other choice is *Technology Schematic*, which shows how the logic maps to device-specific low-level elements such as slices and IOB.

Comment: Addendum: The RTL viewer allows you to dive from top-level into your design, or to select specific components which should be drawn after start up.